# Uncaught Error: invalid keyPath in immutable js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, immutable.js

I am just creating a function to update existing value from my state with immutable js even though the code look fine to me it throws invalid KeyPath Err

```
        const initialState = fromJS({
            all:[],
            tags:[],
            isPaginationData:true,
            isContactFetchingPagination:false
        });
    .....
        const findAndUpdateContact = (state,action) => {
            let {payload} = action;
            let findIndex = state.get('all').findIndex(i => i._id === payload._id);
            if(findIndex !== -1){
                console.log(typeof findIndex,findIndex);// Returns number , 0

                console.log(state.deleteIn(['all',findIndex]),"New State"); // not deleting throws an error

                return state
            }else {
                return state
            }
        };

....
```

Comment: Why are you using `deleteIn` to update your data?

Comment: is there a better choice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `setIn` to update your data once you have found the index you want to update.
I would first find the index (as you did):

```
let findIndex = state.get('all').findIndex(i => i.get('_id') === payload._id);
```

and then update the state with:

```
return state.setIn(['all', findIndex], 'new state');
```